# getRotation always returning 0 in Android

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm trying to get the rotation in Android like this:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager)
           context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int rotation = display.getRotation();
```

but rotation is always 0 despite that I'm rotating the phone in the four available positions.

Am I missing something?
I'm using a real phone (Samsung Galaxy S2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know that if the screen is locked the rotation is not computed, I'll try creating a WAKE_LOCK.
Thanks! Guillermo.

Comment: So what is your solution then?